# Trying to make a Pointer to a dynamically allocated char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I'm trying to allocate a `char` array on the heap and then make a pointer to it:

```
char * head;

char * coolArray = new char[5];
```

This should allocate 5 bits on the heap with chars correct?

```
head = &coolArray;
```

Not able to do this ^ due to `&coolArray` being a `char **`?

I am able to fix it by doing:

```
head = *&coolArray;
```

But I'm not sure why this works.

Can anyone explain this concept of pointing to something that is on the heap?

Comment: 5 bytes, not bits. Doing `head = &coolArray` gets the address of `coolArray`, which is a pointer to a pointer of characters, and tries to assign it to `head`, which is just a character pointer. The types don't match. `*&coolArray` references then deferences the value, which will just end up being `head = coolArray`, the correct assignment type.

Comment: Unary `*` and `&` on pointers are the inverse/opposite of each other - `&` is the "address of" operator, while `*` is the dereference (aka "get a reference to what is at that address") operator.   So `head = *&coolArray` is exactly equivalent to `head = coolArray`.   This is completely unrelated to whether what is pointed at is on the "heap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, before anything else, use **`std::string`** to handle character strings.

Except for purposes of learning, generally *don't use* raw arrays, pointers and `new` expressions.

---

> **”** This should allocate 5 bits

No, it allocates 5 *bytes*.

A byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory in C++. Types `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char`, as well as with C++17 and later `std::byte`, are all guaranteed byte size. The number of bits per byte is usually 8, and is at least 8, but can be larger, and is given by the `CHAR_BIT` constant from the `<limits.h>` header.

---

> ```
> head = &coolArray;
> ```

Just write

```
head = coolArray;
```

This assigns a pointer value (the one in the pointer variable `coolArray`) to a pointer variable.

---

> ```
> head = *&coolArray;
> ```

Generally, for any variable `v`, the expression `&v` gives you a pointer to that variable.

Dereferencing that pointer, `*&v`, denotes the same variable. So you could just write `v` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The "heap" and memory allocations are red herrings.

`&coolArray` is "where `coolArray` is".
`*p` is "the thing that is at the location `p`".
`*&x` is "the thing that is where `coolArray` is", which is `coolArray`.

This works pretty much like the real world – "the person who lives in the house where Jack lives" is Jack himself, right?

Incidentally, you could also write `head = coolArray;`.